# PHP dropdown database code not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have an issue with the below code, it is showing the html part but not the data from my database. I am just trying to have the data from the database in the drop down list and when I click `find` to display it on the table below. Can you please help?

```
    <?php
    include 'config.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="manufacturer">
            <option value="">----ALL----</option>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT id, manufacturer FROM coop";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo "<option value='$r[id]'> $r[manufacturer]</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="find" value="find"/>
        <br><br>

        <table border="1">
            <tr align="center">
                <th>ID</th> <th>Manufacturer</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
                {
                    $des=$_POST["manufacturer"];
                    if($des=="")
                    {
                        $result=  mysqli_query("SELECT id, manufacturer FROM coop");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result= mysqli_query($sql);
                    }
                    echo "<tr><td colspan='5'></td></tr>";
                    while($r= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td align='center'>$r[0]</td>";
                        echo "<td width='200'>$r[1]" . " $r[2]</td>";
                        echo "<td alig='center' width='40'> $r[3]</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' width='200'>$r[4]</td>";
                        echo "<td width='100' align='center'>$r[5]</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your web browser, do whatever you have to do to view the source code of the page. Is the PHP visible in the source code in the web browser? If it is, that's the problem. If it isn't, the next step is to look at the error logs.

Comment: You're also just assuming that the queries are successful. Not to mention that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and since you're using `mysqli_` you should start using prepared statements where there are userinput involved.

Comment: I don't see any errors it is showing the table and the drop down list and that is all I can see

Comment: Your fetching associative but have `$r[0]`.. That should be `id` in the index for the value attribute and `manufacturer` for the value. You also don't have a `form`, and are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you! I've played a little bit with the code based on all of your suggestions and now I have the database details in the drop down list but it is not posting it in the table :)

Comment: Update the code in the question to your updated code.

Comment: @chris85 you can see the code, I've replaced it now with the changes I've made

Comment: An `input` doesn't submit without a `form`; or some `js`, did you write `js` for this?

Comment: I was looking in the form option but no js made for it

Answer (score 0):

your `queries` are wrong here

```
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT id, manufacturer FROM coop";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0]</option>";
        }
    ?>
```

this `while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))` should be             `while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result ))`

you should fetch your assoc with `$result` not with`$sql`

still you have some error bellow part